# meteor deploy fails with message "Expired credential"

Tags: meteor

I recently tried to deploy an updated version of my app. Previously, I would simply run:

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com
```

without problem (myapp is just a placeholder for my actual app name). Now, after no changes to my system other than a OSX Mavericks patch, it fails. The command (and other commands):

```
meteor list-sites
```

returns "Couldn't list sites: Expired credential. Please log in again."

When I try to deploy my app with:

```
meteor deploy myapp.meteor.com
```

After username/password prompts, I get the message "Error deploying application: login failed." Login though the meteor.com website works with the same username/password. Running the meteor command with --debug gives no additional information.

Answer (score 16):

OK, here's what worked.

First logout with:

```
meteor logout
```

Then log back in, but the username is NOT the email address you use to sign in to your developer account on meteor.com website. When you log in to the meteor.com website using your email address and password, in the top right hand corner of your browser is another username that you will have created when you set up your meteor developer account. You must use that username to login from your app directory. To be clear:

```
username_website: MyEmailAddress@mail.com
username_meteor: MyUserName (whatever you set up when you created your developer account)
password: MyPassword
```

To log into your meteor developer account at meteor.com use the combination:

```
username_website / password
```

To log into your meteor developer account from your meteor app directory using the command "meteor login" use the combination:

```
username_meteor / password
```

After that "Expired Credential" goes away and you can again deploy your app.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you just have to log in again

You may have to log out first, not always.

```
meteor logout
```

Run this to relogin

```
meteor login
```

Comment: Login using "meteor login" fails. To be clear, I can login to the meteor.com website with my usual username/password; but, when I try to login with the same username/password from an app directory in terminal, or try to deploy from that directory, it fails.

Comment: I"m having this problem as well, I can sign into the meteor website, but I cannot sign in with meteor login

Comment: Finally worked for me but I had to explicitly logout `meteor logout`